# Soft: Lagrange Multiplier and Intersection of Thickened Sets

Tags: soft-question, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Suppose I have an optimization problem of the form
$$
\inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} f(x),
$$
for some convex function $f$ and non-convex l.s.c. function $g$.

Can we reinterpret the Lagrange multiplier $\mu$, as the reciprocal of smallest $\lambda \in [0,1]$ such that the set
$$
\operatorname{arginf} \left[
 (1-\lambda)f(x) + \lambda g(x)
\right] \cap 
\{
x \in \mathbb{R}^d : g(x)=0
\} \neq \emptyset \text{?}
$$

*(sort of a first point of contact)*

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} f(x)$ to $\displaystyle \inf_{\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: g(x)=0\}} f(x). \vphantom{\frac 1 {\displaystyle\int}}$ The backslash does not only prevent italicization but also affects the format in the way that you see in this example. It also affects spacing in things like $a\inf b$ and $a\inf(b). \qquad$